# JQuery selector for div within div based on id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp-classic

I have the following classic ASP:

```
<div class="TabContent">
<%
for i = 1 to 6
%>
    <div id=<%=i%>>
        TabDetail = <%=i%>
    </div>
<%
next
%></div>
```

I'm trying to access a single div element with the following JQuery selector:

```
$(".TabContent > div#1")
```

But it's not finding it. There's definitely a div with an id of 1, so I can't figure out why it's not working!

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: ID's usually shouldn't start with digits. And are unique across the whole document. So `$('#id')` should work. You should also quote the attribute: `<div id="<%=i%>">`

Comment: When are you executing `$(".TabContent > div#1")`? In order to select elements you have to do it after they are created. Also are you sure the elements are direct children (`>`) of `.TabContent`

Comment: @andlrc That restriction on IDs was removed in HTML5. And while quotes are always a good idea, they're only required if the attribute contains spaces or other special characters.

Comment: Did you look at the generated html? Does it add any elements between tabcontent and the div with the id? Otherwise it's a timing issue

Comment: As @PatrickEvans says, you need to make sure the document is loaded before calling the JQuery on it.  But it SHOULD work.  https://jsfiddle.net/d49u2aub/

Comment: @Barmar Thanks for clarifying. :-)

Comment: To get the best possible answer please [edit the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/37447146/edit) and show the full generated HTML, showing Classic ASP code here is pointless as it happens server-side before the result is sent to the client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that `id` isn't being used elsewhere.  Your code does work fine:  https://jsfiddle.net/jay08tbz/

Answer (score 3):

I'm not too familiar with asp. But if you're following good practice, each ID should only be used once on a page. So if there is only one tag with the ID of "1" you can just use jquery as:

```
$("#1")
```

Comment: It's inconsequential because it has nothing to do with Classic ASP as the content is processed server-side and raw HTML is sent to the client, issues with accessing the DOM via JavaScript is a timing issue.